# How to add the row names to my `gt()` table?

Tags: model, data-analysis

I don't know how to add the row names that are included in my dataframe to my `gt()` table

I firstly, created a dataframe including the output from a `drop1` command (which is used for model selection):

**the code:**
drop1_output <- drop1(model, test = "Chi")

Creating a dataframe like so...

however, when I try to create a table of this, the row names (e.g. age_category:gender etc) don't appear.

**here this code i used for creating the table:**
drop1_output %>%
gt() %>%
tab_header(title = md("**Model Selection Output**"), subtitle = "GLMM with binomial distribution")

I'm not to sure how I would go about solving this issue??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZUbd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the argument

> rownames_to_stub = T

inside gt() function.